# When/why did Lisps start using semicolons for comments?

Tags: lisp, programming-languages, history

What is the history of the semicolon being used for comments in Lisp and its dialects?

A guy in our group thought Clojure's use of the semicolon was an in-your-face to Java & Co. at first.

I mentioned that Lisp was older than C, but I realized that:

- C wasn't the first language to use the semicolon as statement separator (what was? Algol?)
- I don't know **when** Lisps began using semicolons for comments
- and I don't know **why** Lisps began using semicolons for comments

Comment: Just a side note: Ada is not older than C, so it's definitely not the first language to use semicolons as statement terminators. You might be thinking of ALGOL (which might very well be the first language to do so).

Comment: Many assembly languages use semicolons for comments, and lisp being an older language, may have gotten it from there. Just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semicolons look to be statement sequencers (rather than terminators) in Algol68.

LISP 1.5 was punch card based, so comments probably would've been written on the cards themselves, I think? The manual gives no indication that there was a mechanism for in-language comments.

The Stanford Lisp 1.6 manual shows semicolon comments.

As for the origins, I'd look to see what if anything early assemblers used for indicating comments. Certainly the semicolon is common enough in current ones.

Comment: Are you sure? The Stanford LISP 1.6 Manual I just Googled up shows comments as beginning with "<ASCII 176>" (which appears to be a nonsense character nowadays). And the LISP 1.5 manual I found actually documents an infix syntax with semicolons used for argument separators (e.g. `apply[u;v]`).

Comment: Those semicolons are appearing in M expressions, not S expressions. My understanding is that the M expressions were for reasoning about, and the S expressions were what actually got entered. Certainly the S expressions are what we've still got today. As for the semicolons in 1.6, I found them in the example code in the appendix on ALVINE.

Comment: How did they program in LISP on punch cards? Weren't punch cards used just to encode binary?

Comment: Well, my first guess is that they used ASCII, but I suppose it depended on what convention their software followed.

Answer (score 2):

Maclisp from 1974 had semicolon as comments.

http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/Moon-MACLISP_Reference_Manual-Apr_08_1974.pdf